# jQuery get random option value from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone help provide the jQuery to be able to randomly select an option from an existing select object?
For example:

```
<select id="items">
    <option value="1">Item A</option>
    <option value="4">Item B/option>
    <option value="8">Item C</option>
</select>
```

Since the values are not sequential, I assume I can't use the `$('#items option').length` as a multiplier for `Math.random`.

Comment: Yes you can, you're selecting an `option` element, *not* a given `value`. The `value` and option-index are *not* the same thing.

Comment: Sure you can. Indexing into that array doesn't depend on what the values of the options are.

Answer (score 2):

```
var options = $('#items option'),
    min     = 0,
    max     = options.length,
    rand    = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

var random_option_value = options.eq( rand ).text();

// to set the select to a random option, do :
// $('#item').val( options.eq( rand ).val() );
```

Make sure you close the middle `option`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var length = $('#items option').length;
var pick = Math.floor(Math.random()*length);
var randomOption = $('#items option')[pick];
```